# Is there something under way to solve the topic intersection and mess of SO and sibling sites? Is there already a plan for this matter?

Tags: support, questions, stack-exchange, migration, asking-questions

I had a situation, searched the web, found nothing, wanted to ask on SO, thought to ask on https://dba.stackexchange.com/ , but saw that on SO is also a huge community and 30 times more questions to this tag, were anxious to do something wrong, pondered,
and **eventually**,
wrote the question on **SO**,
because there is the most related to the topic, most boom, most attention, simply because the most do it so, and generally there is no compulsory process and no rigour execution.

My question I am talking about is [Oracle: How to round and update all numbers in a table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19260595/oracle-how-to-round-and-update-all-numbers-in-a-table) .
And speaking of the [*oracle*](https://dba.stackexchange.com/tags/oracle) tag, there are approx. 100 questions, tagged with *oracle*, every day on SO. So, **when ckecking how the major part does**, one can conclude, its OK to post here on SO, it cannot be unwelcome..

## This thread specific question set:

1. **Why** are these database tags, respectively this e.g. *oracle* tag is open for asking specific database questions **and why** are new questions to databases are not strict moved to dba.stackexchange, because this is the correct site and there is already a oracle tag?
2. Migration is already a much discussed topic. **Is there** maybe already such a *migration peer group*, *migration projects*?
3. Depending on 2.==true: If there are such migration projects, **what** is done resp. is there already something **considered** to prevent or forbid the reappearance of countless e.g. database questions again on SO?
4. **Is there** a **usergiude**, a **faq section**, a **help site**, **explicitly** dedicated to find the right stackexchange site, **how** to prevent topic mixture and explanations whats the problem and what is done against it?
5. **Is there** something under way to solve this topic intersection and mess of SO and sibling sites? **Is there** already a scheduled plan, a running project, a built think tank, a delegated group for this matter? So that I can feel reassured, that it is not my sole worry and that *something* will come.

Please answer information to this list what is **officially planned** respectively **under way**.

**Anttention!** This should not be another thread for twaddle, ideas and not a subjective pool for all-wise answers..
**Also!** The thread deals not direct with this oracle example, but general about some overlapping topics and tags, which are natural because SO was the first site online.

I please would like to get information, if there is something, that addresses already this problem, if there are running things, if this is already a topic on the schedule/to do list of the leading people and higher ranks here!

Comment: There's a huge difference between programming and administering Oracle, for instance. Or getting it network connectivity.

Comment: I believe things are only migrated if they are actively off topic on the site they're posted on. And I think the overlap is smaller than you think

Comment: Posts on Oracle are on-topic on SO. I'm not sure your question is on topic for DBA.SE...  if you look at what's [on topic](http://dba.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) basic SQL queries are not. So, yes, it's perfectly alright to post that sort of question on SO. You might want to do a little bit more research first though. Typing `round` into the [Oracle docs](http://www.oracle.com/pls/db112/search?remark=quick_search&word=round) would have given you your answer.

Comment: "Stackoverflow is the starting point of this network and we know, first of all, everything somehow related to computers was put to SO." - This isn't accurate. Stack Overflow has always been limited in scope to programming-related questions. Sure, what we considered related was once broad enough to encompass workplace issues or the best programmer keyboards, but it's always been about programming. The other sites have been created to cover areas that Stack Overflow does not.

Comment: Is this question, in a nut shell; "What should happen when a question is on topic on more than one site"

Comment: The goal is to create a Q&A site for the whole world @Florian. You asked why every Oracle question should not be moved to DBA.SE, I answered that as I believe it might not be on-topic and that it _is_ perfectly on-topic for SO. However, building a Q&A site for the whole world does not necessarily mean that your question hasn't already been answered and isn't easy to understand from the docs. There _are_ quite a few questions on SO already about rounding in Oracle and SQL. How does adding another help the world? _contd_...

Comment: _contd_ Your question also reads as though you're expecting others to do your work for you. I'm not saying that this is actually the case but appearances are important when you can't see and don't know the person you're interacting with. I would recommend reading the [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/). Your other questions clearly show your effort so far... why is this one different? I'm sorry I didn't answer immediately, I was at work. P.S., I haven't downvoted this question either...

Comment: Unpopular suggestions usually stop hemoraging votes after an answer is accepted.  Although I'd be lying if I said I was ever 100% sure what this was about

Comment: I think it may be because this post had a lot of "noise" in it, what was "Unrest, perfection" even about?! I think it distracted from your question

Comment: Sorry, but your question sounds more like a big rant; there's too much complaining and not enough substance. There's a huge difference between a question about driving a car and a question about maintaining or fixing a car, just as there are clear differences between how to query data (programming, or SO) and how to configure, maintain, or repair Oracle databases/servers/instances (database maintenance, or DBA). Reading the help pages on each site describe the differences fairly clearly, and where there's doubt you can ask here and we'll help you decide.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, there is already a plan under way for this matter. It goes like this:

- users do their best to choose the right site. For example you might ask some of your database questions on dba.se if they are about administering the database, and others on SO if they are programming questions. You might get it wrong. That's ok.
- other users on the site can notice off-topic questions and arrange for them to be migrated to the correct site
- once on the right site, your question will get the answers you want

In addition, each site has a lot of information about on- and off-topic questions, and tag wikis also help. For example, [the tag wiki for Oracle on dba.se](https://dba.stackexchange.com/tags/oracle/info) and [on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/oracle/info) are very different. However since many users don't read that sort of thing, the vote-to-close and migration options do the cleanup for them.

It's best not to try to mess with the system by posting to both places. You'll waste people's time, and one will get closed as a duplicate in the end.

Comment: We shouldn't be closing cross-site duplicates.

Comment: No, I meant once it has migrated. I've seen that a lot between programmers and SO. Someone comments it belongs on the other site, the OP reposts, eventually it migrates and is now a dupe of the handposted copy from the OP.

Comment: Don't delete questions that didn't go the way you like. Just ask a different one.